# Beamer, fix-cm math mode, - no asterisk?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I'm using `beamer` to make a presentation.  In order to fit a large table onto a slide, I'm using `fix-cm` and `\fontsize` to customize the font size and spacing.  The table is produced by `estout`, which uses asterisk in math mode.  Oddly though, the asterisks in math mode don't appear in the compiled PDF when I use `beamer` and `\fontsize`.  It works when I don't use `beamer`, and when I don't use `\fontsize`. Other numbers work in math mode.

Any ideas?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{beamer}[10]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\fontsize{.5}{6}\selectfont
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
1$^{5}$\\
2***\\
3$^{*}$\\
$*$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX gets very confused by you asking for a font size of half a point. What's your intention?

Comment: Also the document compiles and I see starred numbers. But only the 2*** one

Comment: My intention of the decimal was to fine-tune the font until it fit perfectly.  It has no bearing on this question, does it? I included the 2*** to demonstrate that it's something to do with math mode.  I should have been more clear that this only is a problem in math mode.

Comment: Even with `fix-cm` TeX doesn't handle Computer Modern fonts on sizes less than 5. What's the point in requesting a font size of 0.5pt? Which means slightly less than 0.2 millimeters. It *has* bearing to the question, of course: LaTeX is unable to assign proper math fonts at that size.

Comment: The asterisks aren't missing.  They're just so small you can't see them.  If you view the document at 1000X you will see very tiny asterisks.

Comment: In beamer 0.5pt makes sense - it's projected onto a screen and is much more readable than anything much larger.  That said, you seem to be on the right track - it works fine for larger fonts.  However, I need to find a way to make the font approximately that small.

Comment: you're right - they are there! then why are they disproportionately shrunk?

Comment: I guess I'll just have to use \tiny and cede more precise control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the math `*` is so small is that that is the only character that comes out the size that you have asked for. You have asked for 0.5pt font which is impossibly small. Most of the text fonts give warnings like

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <0.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 17.
```

so you get 5pt rather than 0.5pt font size so you can see the character.

however the math font setup slipped through the cracks and did not apply a font substitution, and you asked for a subscript sized asterisk on a 0.5pt textfont size. If you add `\showoutput` to your document you will see that you got what you asked for:-)

```
...........\OMS/cmsy/m/n/0.34999 ^^C
```

so a 0.35pt font size. This is small, very small, and not really visible unless you magnify the document.

Change to

```
\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont
```

None of the other characters will change size but you will get a math `*` of appropriate size.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue a `\fontsize{<dimen>}{<dimen>}\selectfont` declaration, when TeX finds a formula it tries to supply proper math fonts. In `fontmath.ltx` one finds the lines

```
\DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

which tell what font sizes to assign for normal symbols, and first and second level subscripts and superscripts, when the size is specified in one of the first arguments.

If you really want to fine tune the appearance, you should also issue a line of that kind. Indeed, when you ask for an undeclared font size, LaTeX does its best to guess. For example, when you ask for a font size of 8.5pt, it will assign 8pt for normal math size, 6pt for superscripts and 5pt for second. This is hardly what you want.

Try your input with `\usepackage{lmodern}` and you'll see some small ants (if you magnify very much the PDF).

As an aside, one should observe that there's a strange interaction with beamer that seems to make it *not* recognize what's done by `fix-cm`; then there's something unclear about the `table` environment. But this is, in my opinion, irrelevant.